Need to optimize the code for multiple-connection-model Injection (here UserModel)
Connection names are imported from a constant file, which can be modified if required. The same connection name is used for making connections with Mongo.
I am looking for optimization in UserRepository for which the image is attached of UserRepository and AbstractRepository.
Required to solve:

The injection should be made from a constant by iterating or something like that.
Injection variable should be used in super()

// User Repository
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { AbstractRepository } from '../abstract.repository';
import { User } from '../models';
import { instanceKeys } from '@app/common/config';

@Injectable()
export class UsersRepository extends AbstractRepository<User> {
    protected readonly logger = new Logger(UsersRepository.name);
    static conn = instanceKeys; // ['staging', 'LPU', 'BBIT']

    constructor(
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[0] ? UsersRepository.conn[0] : 'staging') conn0: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[1] ? UsersRepository.conn[1] : 'staging') conn1: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[2] ? UsersRepository.conn[2] : 'staging') conn2: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[3] ? UsersRepository.conn[3] : 'staging') conn3: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[4] ? UsersRepository.conn[4] : 'staging') conn4: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[5] ? UsersRepository.conn[5] : 'staging') conn5: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[6] ? UsersRepository.conn[6] : 'staging') conn6: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[7] ? UsersRepository.conn[7] : 'staging') conn7: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[8] ? UsersRepository.conn[8] : 'staging') conn8: Model<User>,
      @InjectModel(User.name, UsersRepository.conn[9] ? UsersRepository.conn[9] : 'staging') conn9: Model<User>,
    ) {
       // we are using `.at()` to give value as undefined instead of generating an error, 
      //  and there will be only one key that will be `undefined` in object passed to super
      super({
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(0)]: conn0,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(1)]: conn1,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(2)]: conn2,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(3)]: conn3,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(4)]: conn4,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(5)]: conn5,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(6)]: conn6,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(7)]: conn7,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(8)]: conn8,
        [UsersRepository.conn.at(9)]: conn9,
      });
    }

    setInstanceKey(instanceKey: string) {
      AbstractRepository.instanceKey = instanceKey;
    }
  }

// Abstract Repository
import { ExecutionContext, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FilterQuery, Model, Types, UpdateQuery, UpdateWriteOpResult, QueryOptions, ProjectionType, AggregateOptions, PopulateOptions, InferId } from 'mongoose';
import { AbstractDocument } from '@app/common';
import { CreateIndexesOptions, DeleteOptions, DeleteResult, ObjectId, UpdateOptions } from 'mongodb';
import { GrpcInternalException } from 'nestjs-grpc-exceptions';

export abstract class AbstractRepository<TDocument extends AbstractDocument> {
    protected abstract readonly logger: Logger;
    static instanceKey: string = "staging";

    constructor(protected readonly model: any) {
      console.log(model)
    }

    async create(doc: Omit<TDocument, '_id'>, options?: QueryOptions<TDocument>): Promise<TDocument> {
      console.log("Create Abstract>>", AbstractRepository.instanceKey);
      if (!AbstractRepository.instanceKey) {
        throw `Instance key not defined for ${this.constructor.name}`;
      }
      const _id = new Types.ObjectId();
      const createdDocument = new this.model[AbstractRepository.instanceKey]({
        ...doc,
        _id: new Types.ObjectId(),
      });
      try {
        return (await createdDocument.save(options)).toJSON() as unknown as TDocument;
      } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error('Error creating document:', error);
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }

I have tried Property Based injection and Module Ref but it didn't helped out.
